# Adding new options to rails select/radio buttons/ checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, checkbox, radio-button

I have a form with many fields with checkboxes and radio buttons. I wish to add an "Other" option in each of them. Now if the user click on other option, he should be allowed to add new option that should be saved in database for future use.

Here is my current code:

```
<label> Goals: </label><br>
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :goal_id, Admin::Goal.all, :id, :title, checked: @assessment.goal_id, :include_hidden => false do |b| %>
  <%= b.label class:"label-checkbox" do %>
   <%= b.check_box + b.text%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: check my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to customize `collection_check_box` like this:

```
<% other_options = [{id: "other",title: "other"}] %>

<label> Goals: </label><br>
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :goal_id, Admin::Goal.all + other_options, lambda{|a|a["id"]}, lambda{|a|a["title"], checked: @assessment.goal_id, :include_hidden => false do |b| %>
  <%= b.label class:"label-checkbox" do %>
   <%= b.check_box + b.object[:title]%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What I am doing here:

- Merging other_option array and your goal collection array.
- other array is not Relation so you need to modify how id,title are fetched. So I am using lambda to access same.
- b.text will work if you are using only Goal. Since we are using our custom hash i.e other_option array we need to access value as b.object and then access title. This will work for both.